# WatiN - Cannot add ReturnDialogHandler to existing WebBrowser

Tags: exception, dialog, handler, watin

I'm trying to click the "OK" button of a javascript alert window. However the method `AddDialogHandler` throws ***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*** What am I doing wrong?

```cs
// Class
IE browser;

button_click()
{
     var thread = new Thread(() =>
     {
        WatiN.Core.Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher = false;
        browser = new IE(webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance);

        ReturnDialogHandler myHandler = new ReturnDialogHandler();

        browser.AddDialogHandler(myHandler); // This line throws exception

        browser.Button(Find.ById("alertButton")).ClickNoWait();
        myHandler.WaitUntilExists();

        myHandler.OKButton.Click();

        browser.WaitForComplete();

     });
     thread.Name = "KillAlertWindowAsync";
     thread.IsBackground = true;
     thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
     thread.Start();
   }
}
```

Comment: Is it a generic ok dialog window?

Comment: It's a simple javascript alert.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var approveConfirmDialog = new ConfirmDialogHandler();

using (new UseDialogOnce(Browser.DialogWatcher, approveConfirmDialog))
{
       //Your code to invoke popup.

       approveConfirmDialog.WaitUntilExists(); 
       approveConfirmDialog.OKButton.Click();
}
```

This is assuming it is a generic ok pop-up.

Comment: I'll try it and see what happens, but my main problem is how to add the handler to an existing browser instance.

Comment: @Souvlaki This should all be handled in the same browser instance. There is no additional instance being created.

Answer (score 0):

Using Emerica's code, he's using "Browser.DialogWatcher" which is a new instance.  That should only work if your browser is static.  Since you've got a browser object defined as

```
browser = new IE(webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance);
```

you can instead use "browser.DialogWatcher" to call that specific instance.  One thing to note however is there is a known issue with IE9 and dialogs.  I'd suggest making sure you have the latest 2.1 WatiN version. Assuming you already have that version, try setting IE to use IE 8 to confirm it's not an IE 9 - WatiN compatibility issue.  To do that, just hit F12 in your Browser and switch the Browser & Document Mode to IE8.